# UITableView without UITableViewController code not working

Tags: objective-c, ios, nsmutablearray, uitableview

I've used the following code in a normal UIViewController with some other contents, the table view is on the bottom part of the view:

```
- (NSInteger)numberOfSectionsInTableView:(UITableView *)tableView
{
    // Return the number of sections.
    return 1;
}

- (NSInteger)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView numberOfRowsInSection:(NSInteger)section
{
 // Return the number of rows in the section.
    return [names count];
}

- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    static NSString *CellIdentifier = @"namen";
    UITableViewCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:CellIdentifier];

    // Configure the cell...
    NSString *cellValue = [names objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];
    cell.textLabel.text = cellValue;

    return cell;
}
```

And a NSMutableArray called names (with 4 objects)

Comment: set or connect the datasource and delegate of your table view to your view controller. accept the answer and vote up the answer, if following answers have helped you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This code doesn't work with a UITableViewController, either... You'll need to create your table view cell in `-tableView:cellForRowAtIndexPath:`. When you dequeue cells, the return value might be nil, if there are no cells that can be dequeued.

```
- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    static NSString *CellIdentifier = @"namen";
    UITableViewCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:CellIdentifier];

    // Create the cell if it could not be dequeued
    if (cell == nil)
        cell = [[UITableViewCell alloc] initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleDefault reuseIdentifier:CellIdentifier];

    // Configure the cell...
    NSString *cellValue = [names objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];
    cell.textLabel.text = cellValue;

    return cell;
}
```

Answer (score 2):

You need to set the table view's [data source](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/uikit/reference/UITableViewDataSource_Protocol/Reference/Reference.html) and [delegate](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/uikit/reference/UITableViewDelegate_Protocol/Reference/Reference.html) to your UIViewController, and implement the required methods for both protocols.

Comment: this is the implentation, right? <UITableViewDelegate, UITableViewDataSource> - but how to connect, can't see the outlets.

Comment: @user1607001 If this answer has helped you solve your problem, please be sure to mark it as correct by clicking the "check mark" next to the answer.

Comment: An example would have been helpful here. Apples documentation is really tedious and has zero inline examples.

Answer (score 0):

You've probably forgotten to set your view controller as the table view's `dataSource` (`UITableViewController` does this automatically).

Comment: That's the one with Outlet's right? But the Outlets for delegate aren't there (using storyboard)